# Finding a new programming language for web development?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm wondering if there are any *less-biased* resources that give good, *specific overviews* of programming languages and their intended goals. I would like to learn a new language, but visiting the sites of each language isn't working. Each one talks about how great it is without much mention of it's weaknesses or [specific goals](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).

> Ruby is a dynamic, open source
> programming language with a focus on
> simplicity and productivity.
>
> Python is a programming language that
> lets you work more quickly and
> integrate your systems more
> effectively.

Having been a PHP developer for years, [Vic Cherubini](http://leftnode.com/entry/im-retiring-from-php) sums up my plight well:

> I knew PHP well, had my own framework,
> and could work quickly to get
> something up and running.
>
> I programmed like this throughout the
> MVC revolution. I got better and
> better jobs (read: better paying,
> better title) as a PHP developer, but
> all along the way realizing that the
> code I wrote on my own time was great,
> and the code I worked with at work was
> horrible. Like, worse than horrible.
> Atrocious. OS Commerce level bad.
> Having side projects kept me sane,
> because the code I worked with at work
> made me miserable.
>
> This is why I'm retiring from PHP for
> my side projects and new programming
> ventures. I'm spent with PHP.
> Exhausted, if you will. I've reached a
> level where I think I'm at the top
> with it as a language and if I don't
> move on to a new language soon, I'll
> be done completely with programming
> and I do not want that.

Languages I've looked at include JavaScript (for node.js), Ruby, Python, & Erlang. I've even thought about Scala or C++.

**The problem is figuring out which ones are built to handle my needs the best.**

So where can I go to skip the hype and get real information about the maturity of a platform, the size of the community, and the strengths & weaknesses of that language. If I know these then picking a language to continue my web development should be easy.

**Update**

I just don't want to get 4 months down the road with some language and find it sucks because each thread has 4MB of overhead, or the max concurrent connections is 999, there is no package to do "X" feature, or support is being phased out for a new language branch.

Comment: It's hard to tell which will handle your needs best if you don't specify these needs.

Comment: That is why I didn't define my needs - *My personal needs are beside the point*. I want to know where I can look to match my needs to a certain programming language. Because my needs may change and I'll need to go back again.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there is also more to a program than it's [execution speed](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/). Development speed and the *way* you have to build your application (due to the language) play an important role.

Comment: this is less about languages and more about the maturity and feature richness of the frameworks that are available for them.

Comment: Not really, Frameworks can only use what the language already provides.

Comment: Your needs aren't beside the point when the point is that you're asking a bunch of complete strangers on the internet which language you should choose. That's why the highest voted answer atm is "Good Luck".

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/28422d707512283?pli=1) excellent post by Alex Martelli.

Comment: @phant0m, can you post that as an answer, that is one of the best overviews on python and ruby I have ever read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't going to post this as an answer, but Xeoncross asked me to, so here we go:

(Sidenote: if someone could fix the markdown issue in the little code example, I'd appreciate it.)

Posted by **Alex Martelli** on *comp.lang.python*: [What's better about Ruby than Python?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/28422d707512283?pli=1) on *Aug 18 2003, 5:50 pm*

> Erik Max Francis wrote:
>
> > "Brandon J. Van Every" wrote:
> >
> > > What's better about Ruby than Python?  I'm sure there's something. 
> > >       What is it? 
> > >       Wouldn't it make much more sense to ask Ruby people this, rather than 
> > >       Python people?
>
> Might, or might not, depending on
>   one's purposes -- for example, if 
>   one's purposes include a "sociological
>   study" of the Python community,  then
>   putting questions to that community is
>   likely to prove more  revealing of
>   informaiton about it, than putting
>   them elsewhere:-).   Personally, I
>   gladly took the opportunity to follow
>   Dave Thomas'  one-day Ruby tutorial at
>   last OSCON.  Below a thin veneer of
>   syntax  differences, I find Ruby and
>   Python amazingly similar -- if I was 
>   computing the minimum spanning tree
>   among just about any set of 
>   languages, I'm pretty sure Python and
>   Ruby would be the first two  leaves to
>   coalesce into an intermediate node:-).
>
> Sure, I do get weary, in Ruby, of
>   typing the silly "end" at the end  of
>   each block (rather than just
>   unindenting) -- but then I do get  to
>   avoid typing the equally-silly `:`
>   which Python requires at the 
>   *start* of each block, so that's almost a wash:-).  Other syntax 
>   differences such as `@foo` versus
>   `self.foo`, or the higher significance
>   of case in Ruby vs Python, are really
>   just about as irrelevant to me.
>
> Others no doubt base their choice of
>   programming languages on just  such
>   issues, and they generate the hottest
>   debates -- but to me that's  just an
>   example of one of Parkinson's Laws in
>   action (the amount on  debate on an
>   issue is inversely proportional to the
>   issue's actual  importance).   One
>   syntax difference that I do find
>   important, and in Python's  favour --
>   but other people will no doubt think
>   just the reverse --  is "how do you
>   call a function which takes no
>   parameters".  In  Python (like in C),
>   to call a function you always apply
>   the  "call operator" -- trailing
>   parentheses just after the object 
>   you're calling (inside those trailing
>   parentheses go the args  you're
>   passing in the call -- if you're
>   passing no args, then  the parentheses
>   are empty).  This leaves the mere
>   mention of  any object, with no
>   operator involved, as meaning just a 
>   reference to the object -- in any
>   context, without special  cases,
>   exceptions, ad-hoc rules, and the
>   like.  In Ruby (like  in Pascal), to
>   call a function WITH arguments you
>   pass the  args (normally in
>   parentheses, though that is not
>   invariably  the case) -- BUT if the
>   function takes no args then simply 
>   mentioning the function implicitly
>   calls it.  This may meet  the
>   expectations of many people (at least,
>   no doubt, those  whose only previous
>   experience of programming was with
>   Pascal,  or other languages with
>   similar "implcit calling", such as 
>   Visual Basic) -- but to me, it means
>   the mere mention of an  object may
>   EITHER mean a reference to the object,
>   OR a call  to the object, depending on
>   the object's type -- and in those 
>   cases where I can't get a reference to
>   the object by merely  mentioning it I
>   will need to use explicit "give me a
>   reference  to this, DON'T call it!"
>   operators that aren't needed
>   otherwise.  I feel this impacts the
>   "first-classness" of functions (or 
>   methods, or other callable objects)
>   and the possibility of  interchanging
>   objects smoothly.  Therefore, to me,
>   this specific  syntax difference is a
>   serious black mark against Ruby -- but
>   I do understand why others would thing
>   otherwise, even though  I could hardly
>   disagree more vehemently with them:-).
>   Below the syntax, we get into some
>   important differences in  elementary
>   semantics -- for example, strings in
>   Ruby are  mutable objects (like in
>   C++), while in Python they are not 
>   mutable (like in Java, or I believe
>   C#).  Again, people who  judge
>   primarily by what they're already
>   familiar with may  think this is a
>   plus for Ruby (unless they're familiar
>   with  Java or C#, of course:-).  Me, I
>   think immutable strings are  an
>   excellent idea (and I'm not surprised
>   that Java, independently  I think,
>   reinvented that idea which was already
>   in Python), though  I wouldn't mind
>   having a "mutable string buffer" type
>   as well  (and ideally one with better
>   ease-of-use than Java's own  "string
>   buffers"); and I don't give this
>   judgment because of  familiarity --
>   before studying Java, apart from
>   functional  programming languages
>   where *all* data are immutable, all
>   the  languages I knew had mutable
>   strings -- yet when I first saw  the
>   immutable-string idea in Java (which I
>   learned well before  I learned
>   Python), it immediately struck me as
>   excellent, a  very good fit for the
>   reference-semantics of a higher level 
>   programming language (as opposed to
>   the value-semantics that  fit best
>   with languages closer to the machine
>   and farther from  applications, such
>   as C) with strings as a first-class,
>   built-in  (and pretty crucial) data
>   type.
>
> Ruby does have some advantages in
>   elementary semantics -- for  example,
>   the removal of Python's "lists vs
>   tuples" exceedingly  subtle
>   distinction.  But mostly the score (as
>   I keep it, with  simplicity a big plus
>   and subtle, clever distinctions a
>   notable  minus) is against Ruby (e.g.,
>   having both closed and half-open 
>   intervals, with the notations a..b and
>   a...b [anybody wants  to claim that
>   it's *obvious* which is which?-)], is
>   silly --  IMHO, of course!).  Again,
>   people who consider having a lot of 
>   similar but subtly different things at
>   the core of a language  a PLUS, rather
>   than a MINUS, will of course count
>   these "the  other way around" from how
>   I count them:-).
>
> Don't be misled by these comparisons
>   into thinking the two  languages are
>   *very* different, mind you.  They aren't.  But  if I'm asked to compare
>   "capelli d'angelo" to "spaghettini", 
>   after pointing out that these two
>   kinds of pasta are just  about
>   undistinguishable to anybody and
>   interchangeable in any  dish you might
>   want to prepare, I would then
>   inevitably have  to move into
>   microscopic examination of how the
>   lengths and  diameters imperceptibly
>   differ, how the ends of the strands 
>   are tapered in one case and not in the
>   other, and so on -- to  try and
>   explain why I, personally, would
>   rather have capelli  d'angelo as the
>   pasta in any kind of broth, but would
>   prefer  spaghettini as the
>   pastasciutta to go with suitable
>   sauces for  such long thin pasta forms
>   (olive oil, minced garlic, minced  red
>   peppers, and finely ground anchovies,
>   for example - but if  you sliced the
>   garlic and peppers instead of mincing
>   them, then  you should choose the
>   sounder body of spaghetti rather than
>   the  thinner evanescence of
>   spaghettini, and would be well advised
>   to forego the achoview and add instead
>   some fresh spring basil  [or even --
>   I'm a heretic...! -- light mint...]
>   leaves -- at  the very last moment
>   before serving the dish).  Ooops,
>   sorry,  it shows that I'm traveling
>   abroad and haven't had pasta for  a
>   while, I guess.  But the analogy is
>   still pretty good!-)
>
> So, back to Python and Ruby, we come
>   to the two biggies (in  terms of
>   language proper -- leaving the
>   libraries, and other  important
>   ancillaries such as tools and
>   environments, how to  embed/extend
>   each language, etc, etc, out of it for
>   now -- they  wouldn't apply to all
>   IMPLEMENTATIONS of each language
>   anyway,  e.g., Jython vs Classic
>   Python being two implementations of 
>   the Python language!):
>
> 1. Ruby's iterators and codeblocks vs Python's iterators     and generators;
> 2. Ruby's TOTAL, unbridled "dynamicity", including the ability   
>          to "reopen" any existing class,
>      including all built-in ones,     and
>      change its behavior at run-time -- vs
>      Python's vast but     *bounded*
>      dynamicity, which never changes the
>      behavior of     existing built-in
>      classes and their instances.
>
> Personally, I consider [1](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/28422d707512283?pli=1) a wash (the
>   differences are so  deep that I could
>   easily see people hating either
>   approach  and revering the other, but
>   on MY personal scales the pluses  and
>   minuses just about even up); and [2] a
>   crucial issue --  one that makes Ruby
>   much more suitable for "tinkering",
>   BUT  Python equally more suitable for
>   use in large production  applications.
>    It's funny, in a way, because both
>   languages  are so MUCH more dynamic
>   than most others, that in the end  the
>   key difference between them from my
>   POV should hinge on  that -- that Ruby
>   "goes to eleven" in this regard (the 
>   reference here is to "Spinal Tap", of
>   course).  In Ruby,  there are no
>   limits to my creativity -- if I decide
>   that  all string comparisons must
>   become case-insensitive, *I CAN  DO
>   THAT*!  I.e., I can dynamically alter
>   the built-in string  class so that
>
> ```
> a = "Hello World" 
> b = "hello world" 
> if a == b 
>     print "equal!\n" 
> else 
>     print "different!\n" 
> end
> ```
>
> WILL print "equal".  In python, there
>   is NO way I can do  that.  For the
>   purposes of metaprogramming,
>   implementing  experimental frameworks,
>   and the like, this amazing dynamic 
>   ability of Ruby is *extremely*
>   appealing.  BUT -- if we're  talking
>   about large applications, developed by
>   many people  and maintained by even
>   more, including all kinds of libraries
>   from diverse sources, and needing to
>   go into production in  client sites...
>   well, I don't WANT a language that is
>   QUITE  so dynamic, thank you very
>   much.  I loathe the very idea of  some
>   library unwittingly breaking other
>   unrelated ones that  rely on those
>   strings being different -- that's the
>   kind of  deep and deeply hidden
>   "channel", between pieces of code that
>   LOOK separate and SHOULD BE separate,
>   that spells d-e-a-t-h  in large-scale
>   programming.  By letting any module
>   affect the  behavior of any other
>   "covertly", the ability to mutate the 
>   semantics of built-in types is just a
>   BAD idea for production  application
>   programming, just as it's cool for
>   tinkering.
>
> If I had to use Ruby for such a large
>   application, I would  try to rely on
>   coding-style restrictions, lots of
>   tests (to  be rerun whenever ANYTHING
>   changes -- even what should be 
>   totally unrelated...), and the like,
>   to prohibit use of this  language
>   feature.  But NOT having the feature
>   in the first  place is even better, in
>   my opinion -- just as Python itself 
>   would be an even better language for
>   application programming  if a certain
>   number of built-ins could be "nailed
>   down", so  I KNEW that, e.g.,
>   `len("ciao")` is 4 (rather than having
>   to  worry subliminally about whether
>   somebody's changed the  binding of
>   name `len` in the `__builtins__`
>   module...).  I do  hope that
>   eventually Python does "nail down" its
>   built-ins.
>
> But the problem's minor, since
>   rebinding built-ins is quite  a
>   deprecated as well as a rare practice
>   in Python.  In Ruby,  it strikes me as
>   major -- just like the *too powerful*
>   macro  facilities of other languages
>   (such as, say, Dylan) present  similar
>   risks in my own opinion (I do hope
>   that Python never  gets such a
>   powerful macro system, no matter the
>   allure of  "letting people define
>   their own domain-specific little 
>   languages embedded in the language
>   itself" -- it would, IMHO,  impair
>   Python's wonderful usefulness for
>   application  programming, by
>   presenting an "attractive nuisance" to
>   the  would-be tinkerer who lurks in
>   every programmer's heart...).
>
> Alex

Comment: I awarded this as the answer because it is a great, relatively non-biased overview of Ruby and Python as a whole. Explaining how the languages work and *don't work*.

Answer (score 27):

## Good Luck

None of the example descriptions given are objective or testable. They're all hype and opinion.

> ...simplicity and productivity...more quickly...more effectively.

## Try It

Take a small sample project of the kind you are likely to be doing, and try it with all of the languages that interest you. Then post your objective review, and we'll all know.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however it wouldn't work in the real world. Without spending the time fully understanding each language - I could never foresee the full design pattern problem and benefits each system could provide. I'm sure it would take months of working in each language to achieve a high-level understanding of the language itself. I would rather hear from tire experts than spend months deengineering each wheel to figure out why they built it like that.

Still, after I have some good candidates I will certainly do this.

Comment: @Xeoncross: with each language you try, you'll increase your experience, and you'll be able to leverage it in other languages. 4 months to dive into a language are never lost; and if the language is really crap, you need less than two weeks to find out.

Comment: That's true, it should only take a couple weeks to build out something and I would benefit from the experience since languages generally follow other languages.

Comment: Yes, you probably should try all these languages to find a good fit.  But the problem is that when you use a new language you don't use it the way you are supposed to initially.  You end up doing the same damn thing you were doing with the language you already know how to use only with different syntax.  Takes a quite a bit of time to figure out the finer points of each language and what the benefits really are.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was _any significant difference_ between modern languages for general purposes. There, I said it out loud. **And in italics**. Let the flames begin!

Answer (score 8):

I think part of the problem is that anyone who knows enough to comment *meaningfully* about one or more languages is going to have a bias. In almost 4 decades of programming I've worked in more languages than I can count. I can give you opinions (some of them dated) about quite a few of those languages, but none of those opinions will be unbiased.

I take the approach of using the right language for the job. You specifically ask about *web development*, but that's still a pretty broad category -- sort of like saying you're interested in photography. Micro? Astro? etc. Although I agree that PHP is not an emotionally fulfilling language to work in, for many *customers* it's the right language based on any number of factors, not least of which is long-term ability to find programmers to fix the site after you leave and/or get hit by a bus.

So maybe you should look at the types of customers who are interested in projects that lend themselves to something different, and then work on making yourself interesting to them.

Comment: Well, since I'm so good in PHP - I will continue to work in it since I can still make a good living. I was mostly thinking about a new language for my *own* projects. Something to help add some flavor back into my life. I work in just about every are of web development you can think of, NLP, Text parsing, CMS, API's, storage, etc. Also, someone with experience in many languages has *much* less of a bias than people with only one design process.

Comment: Ah. Then I'll give my standard answer to "best language"-type questions: Python. Ignoring "significant whitespace" (which it is possible to do), it is close to a perfect language for me. In addition, there are an amazing number of very high quality libraries out there with Python APIs. E.g. The NLTK, Natural Language Toolkit (http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Ah, but what is it about Python that makes it better? Most languages all share the same toolkits - it's the language design that introduces things like threading, concurrency, VM requirements, compiling/interpreting, persistence, etc.

Comment: Python is just plain fun to program in.  That's what makes it "better" to me.  It's simple enough that you don't need a honking big IDE just to code in it.  But also has a lot of interesting features like objects, functional programming capabilities, many existing libraries/frameworks/tools and a thriving and enthusiastic community with lots of open/free documentation to get you going.

Comment: True. The simplest explanation is that Python works sort of like my brain does and that just makes me more productive; I hardly ever find myself asking, "Now how would I do this in Python?" Although the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) is a bit of a problem, it doesn't tend to affect me that much because I deal more often with *multiprocess* situations (notably multi-stage NL processing pipelines) than *multitask*. I also like the variety of interfacing options for accessing new external libraries: ctypes, Boost, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**Python**

Most universal and general purpose of them all, but also in case of web programming provides wider choice of products. Having standardized WSGI interface guarantees great interoperability between framework and servers. Some of notable Python web products:

- Django — fully-fledged, mature high-level framework with advanced ORM, templating system, form handling, etc.
- Twisted — framework for event-driven (asynchronous) network programming, it can be used for chats, socket servers, web services, you name it.
- Tornado — also event-driven framework, but this one is designed for asynchronous web services.

**Ruby**

Ruby is also quite universal language. But by far it's most notable product is Ruby on Rails. It's design has been inspiration for many (including Django mentioned above).

**JavaScript**

Currently the only server-side choice for JS is node.js. It is very similar to Tornado and Twisted (by which it was inspired). However, it still lacks fully-fledged framework similar to Django or RoR built on top of it.

**Scala**

Being functional language it's great for massively parallel computing, as far as general purpose web programming goes there is Lift — web framework inspired by RoR, used for example by FourSquare.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that things like non-blocking responses, memory usage, concurrency, and other factors are huge in the market for a new language that will power a web application.

Comment: +1 for Django. It blew my mind when I learned it...that, or I was in a dazed stupor because I learned it and Python concurrently. Either way, a great technology I'd like to revisit it my ever-elusive "free time."

Comment: "...it still lacks fully-fledged framework" Check out Express for Node -- http://expressjs.com/

Comment: @T: yeah, I've looked at Express. One of the strong points of Django and RoR is ORM. Express doesn't seem have it.

Answer (score 3):

In my latest web-project I started with PHP because I had used it for web-project before (quick start), but I had many problems with the language e.g bad UTF-8 support and dynamic typing. I also have some Java background and I really enjoy the static typing and good refactoring tools. Java also have good performance compared to PHP. But I also like the expressiveness of functional programming.

### Scala and Play Framework

With the above experience, I really enjoy the Scala programming language, it's statically typed, has support for both object oriented and functional programming and it has good performance compared to other languages used for web development. But I didn't like the web frameworks for Java and servlets, and I found [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) that has support for both [Scala](http://scala.playframework.org/) and Java and it has a very fast development cycle - save the file and update your web page. I have been very satisfied with Scala & Play Framework the last month. But the Scala support in Play Framework is not very mature yet, and neither the tooling support.

In short I recommend Scala as programming language and Play Framework as web framework.

Comment: Play looks cool, haven't had a chance to really (*really*) testdrive it though. Coming from a similar php background, I found [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) to be quite easy to get a grasp of. It also seems to be a little bit more mature than Play, but I'm too new to Scala, to be conclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are looking probably at three types of resources:

- The one which explains the basics of the language and why do you want to use it,
- The one which compares several languages.
- The one which criticizes some aspect of a language.

Both of those resources would be biased.

- When you explain something about a language, you are trying most of the time to convince the reader to use it. So you would rarely say that the language sucks.
- When you compare several languages, you always have a personal preference for one of them.
- When you criticize something, well, it's hardly possible to be neutral.

You may have a chance to find some neutral comparison, but it's very difficult to write one. Personally, I would never be able to write a comparison between a real language and PHP without criticizing PHP all the time. And I'm pretty sure I'm not alone in not being able to be neutral enough.

---

If you want to have an overview of different languages, than you have **to learn them yourself**, and **read a lot**. By learning, I mean knowing the basics of the language, but **being able to have your own opinion**. It's not because you've read a Ruby manual than you're able to explain what is good and what is bad in this language.

This means that you have either to spend time (months, or even years) practicing. Or, you can read a lot. But **try to read contradictory things**. If some person writes that he hates PHP and PHP is one of the worst languages ever, especially compared to real languages like Ruby, C# or Java, try also to find a person who tells that PHP is wonderful, and it's mush easier to use than C#, much faster than Java, and much... (I really don't know what) than Ruby.

Remember one thing: **if you already know well a language, you will be very critic at the beginning when learning another one**, believing that the language you already know is better and much easier to use. It's like Linux users who hate Windows, and Windows users who hate Linux: in fact, neither OS is better; it's just that a Linux user don't know how to use Windows, and vice versa. It's only after you acquire enough experience in both than you will be able to decide correctly which one is better for you.

---

Last thing, often forgotten: it is also very important to be able to evaluate the "surroundings" of a language:

- How good is the framework (or the most used frameworks)?
- Is it easy to find a hosting service? Do you appreciate the IDE?
- Are there plenty of well-written third-party libraries?
- Is the community composed of highly professional developers, or mostly by beginners who don't know anything neither about programming in general, nor about the language itself?
- Is the documentation verbose enough and easy to search and understand?
- Are the language and the frameworks updated frequently?
- etc.

Comment: I totally agree. It's these questions I'm looking for an answer for. You mention **reading a lot** - and that is what I'm trying to do - I need lots of resources to read about the languages I want to look into. While it's not possible to have an un-biased review, some are much more even balanced and that is all I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since one of your criteria seems to be "is fun to work with", I'd think you'd want to find biased info. If the author of something is passionate about their language of choice, there's a pretty good chance they'll give a biased assessment.

Maybe you should approach it from the other direction.  Since you sound like you're talking about making a career move out of it rather than a hobby, perhaps you should survey some job ads, find some interesting technologies/languages and look into those.

As for languages having specific goals, many languages don't have them.  Most of the languages you listed are pretty general purpose.  For instance, the language Ruby is a pretty general purpose language suited for many tasks.  Once you add a framework to it, like [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), that does have a pretty specific goal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you were asking, but if I were looking for something to get me out of a web development professional rut, while still leveraging that experience and contacts, I would get into writing Android and iPhone apps.  Being able to sell an app that complements a client's web site could really make you stand out developing for an internet that is increasingly accessed via mobile devices.

Comment: That really isn't a bad idea. I was also thinking about spending more time in illustrator and Photoshop working on my designs. Still, I would like to find out more about the web application options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really reached the limit of PHP, or just the limits of PHP *as you know it?*

Have you looked into [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)? It's a PHP-based CMS and programming framework which strongly encourages good coding standards and practices. (Having had to work with OSCommerce in previous jobs, I feel your pain there.) Though PHP-based, it's different enough that often the "right" way to do something in pure PHP is not the right way to do it in Drupal, and you're going to have a good learning curve to climb to really master it. However, it may change your perspectives on the capabilities of PHP as a language and web development as a whole.

Comment: The last time I looked at Drupal (4 & 5) it was rather bad. Perhaps their newer versions use proper standards now. Still, as slow as it is I would much rather stick with the awesome frameworks out there.